# Paste Excel range as Picture to Power Point

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have these below two codes and i am trying that when i run the code from Excel then mentioned range should be pasted as picture to PowerPoint.

But i really do not know how to do this. I googled and searched a lot but nothing find your help will be appreciated.

```
Sub convertaspicture()

Application.CutCopyMode = True

Worksheets("Pivot").Range("FC3:FP35").Copy

.Pictures.Paste
End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False


End Sub


Sub CopyToPowerPoint()
 Dim PPT As Object
    Set PPT = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
    PPT.Visible = True
    PPT.Presentations.Open Filename:="C:\Topline\Topline Writeup.pptx"
    Set PPT = Nothing
End Sub
```

Receiving an error:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying a Range as Image is done using the [CopyRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copypicture)-Method

Pasting the image into a Powerpoint Presentation is done using `PasteSpecial`. The following code gives you the idea, it puts the image on the first slide and moves it around a little bit.

```
Sub testSub()
    Const ppFileName = "C:\Topline\Topline Writeup.pptx"

    Dim PPT As Object
    Set PPT = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
    PPT.Visible = True
    ' Use this if file already exists:
    ' PPT.Presentations.Open Filename:=ppFileName
    ' Use this if you want to create a new file:
    PPT.Presentations.Add
    PPT.ActivePresentation.slides.Add Index:=1, Layout:=12 

    Worksheets("Pivot").Range("FC3:FP35").CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    With PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
        .Shapes.PasteSpecial
        With .Shapes(.Shapes.Count)
            .Left = 200
            .Top = 100
            .Width = 500
        End With
    End With
    ' Use this if you want to save an already existing file:
    ' PPT.ActivePresentation.Save
    ' Use this if you want to create a new file:
    PPT.ActivePresentation.SaveAs ppFileName  
    PPT.Quit
    Set PPT = Nothing

End Sub
```

**Update**: If you want to create a new PPT-file, use the command `Add` (instead of `Open`) and `SaveAs` to save the file

```
PPT.Presentations.Add ' <-- No filename here!
..
PPT.ActivePresentation.SaveAs  ppFileName
```

Comment: Thank you very much an error is appearing. I have updated in question

Comment: No clue. Does the file exists, is a valid Powerpoint file and you have access to it? Can you try to open it manually in PP?

Comment: I do not have any existing PPT file. I have excel file where from i run this code and wants excel range will paste as picture to Power Point. Same as we convert excel range to PDF.

Comment: So your example code was misleading. You cannot open a file that doesn't exist (isn't that obvious?). See my update

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry to bother you but where to use this new one at the start or end. Can you please modify the code once.

Comment: ??? As I wrote - use `New` instead of `Open` and `SaveAs`  instead of `Save`.

Comment: I did but still an error `Object does not support this property or method` on this line `PPT.Presentations.new Filename:=ppFileName`

Comment: Sorry, my bad.  It's not `New`, it`s `Add`. And don't use the filename here. The file get's it's name with the SaveAs-method. Updated the answer

Comment: It just open the PPT but does not paste the range as picture. When PPT is open. It is just empty.

Comment: Again my bad. You need to add a slide first when creating a new presentation using VBA. Was not aware about that.

Comment: Still this error is occur when it opens the PPT https://ibb.co/L5SjrQg on this line `PPT.ActivePresentation.SaveAs ppFileName`